# works fine by itself, but blows-up when I put it in the rest of my form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, time, stopwatch

I've hacked away at a stopwatch script to make it useable in several iterations in my HTML form. It uses the id tag to identify which button I pressed to start, end, and reset the timer, post the current time to these fields and runs a stopwatch in a 3rd field. The reason for this is that start/end/duration times will be tracked on 12 vital manufacturing processes via the form.

I've written this in the context of a 'stand-alone' HTML file in order to test the viability and it works just fine... however... when I paste the code into my form (which is seriously too large to post here) and hit the "start" button - I get text posted to my "stopwatch" field and then my page refreshes.

Below is as much of the text that is posting to my field that I can read (if necessary I'll expand the field to capture more of the text) and HTML with the javascript code that I've written.

Posted text:  function hour(serial_number){if(!isFinite(serial_number))return ....

code I've put together:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var sec = 0;
var mins = 0;
var hour = 0;

function duration(ctrlID){
  ctrlbtnID=(ctrlID)
  var cbtnVal=document.getElementById(ctrlbtnID).value;

  if(cbtnVal=='Begin'){
    document.getElementById(ctrlbtnID).value='End';
    var currentTime = new Date()
    var hours = currentTime.getHours()
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
    var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds()

    if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0" + minutes}
    if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0" + seconds}
    bTime= hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " "
    document.getElementById(ctrlbtnID+"Start").value = bTime
  }  //end of if block
  else if(cbtnVal=='End'){
    document.getElementById(ctrlbtnID).value='Begin';
    var currentTime = new Date()
    var hours = currentTime.getHours()
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
    var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds()

    if (minutes < 10) {minutes = "0" + minutes}
    if (seconds < 10) {seconds = "0" + seconds}
    eTime= hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " "
    document.getElementById(ctrlbtnID+"End").value = eTime
  }
  stopwatch();
}
function stopwatch(){
  var x=document.getElementById(ctrlbtnID).value;
  if (x=='End'){
    sec++;
  if (sec == 60) {
    sec = 0;
    mins = mins + 1;
  }
  else {
   mins = mins;
  }  
  if (mins == 60) {
    mins = 0;
    hour += 1;
  }
  if (sec<=9) {
    sec = "0" + sec;
  }
  var swTime=document.getElementById(ctrlbtnID+"Dur");

  swTime.value= ((hour<=9) ? "0"+hour : hour) + " : " + ((mins<=9) ? "0" + mins : mins) + " : " + sec;
  SD=window.setTimeout("stopwatch();", 1000);
  }
}
function reset(){
  var swTime=document.getElementById(ctrlbtnID+"Dur");
  sec = 0;
  mins = 0;
  hour = 0;
  swTime.value='00 : 00 : 00';
  document.getElementById(ctrlbtnID+"Start").value ='00 : 00 : 00';
  document.getElementById(ctrlbtnID+"End").value ='00 : 00 : 00';
}
</script>
</head> 
<body>
<input type="button" value="Begin" id="1_1"  onClick="duration(this.id)"/>
<input type="button" value="Reset" id="reset"  onClick="reset()"/>
<input type="text" value="00 : 00 : 00" id="1_1Dur"/>
<input type="text" value="00 : 00 : 00" id="1_1Start"/>
<input type="text" value="00 : 00 : 00" id="1_1End"/>
</body>
</html>
```

I've posted my first question on here a few days ago - and I've figured out my own issue - but I'm hoping I'll get a better response to this one... I've dug through all of the online resources I could find for about 2 days now and haven't been able to find anything.

Please - I could use some assistance.

Thanks

Comment: for you who want to help Mitch: http://jsfiddle.net/3mYa8/

Comment: Is the start button of type 'submit'? It shouldn't.

Comment: @Ron - thanks for posting it to jsfiddle.net

Comment: @amadeus - no it's not a 'submit' it's an 'input'.

Comment: I've gotten the entirety of the text being sent to my +Dur field: it's returning this string: function hour(serial_number){if(!isFinite(serial_number))return Number.NaN;var res=Math.floor((serial_number-Math.floor(serial_number))*86400+0.5);return Math.floor(res/3600);} : 00 : 34 the time at the end is all I want. I've gotten the issue handled about the refreshing of the page (it no longer does that). I'd like to know why it's returning not only the value I asked for but also what appears to be part of the code generating the value. What is that code from? How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Also, it's not clearing any of the values when pressing 'reset'. However, on a good note the time values for start and end fields are posting.

Comment: @amadeus - your answer about the hour function lead me to discover that my 'reset' function was also just another conflicting naming convention. too many "reset"s in the world! Anyway - just wanted to say a HUGE "Thank You!" for everyone who helped out on this issue. My form works wonderfully now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, you have an `hour(serial_number)` function somewhere, overriding your global hour variable. So please rename either the function or the variable.

As for the 'reset()' function, please tell us if it is called at all, or if it throws an error, and which one.

Comment: I'm assuming you were correct in that after I changed the var hour to var ghour I no longer had an issue with the code showing in my Duration field.

Comment: As for the 'reset()' function - it's called only via a button... and I guess I'm going to take the easy way out and add an attribute to the button and use the same document.getElementById to give me the functionality I need without any grief.  Thanks for your time and patience.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't think we can help you much here without at least some portion of the problematic form. I can confirm that the code works as a stand alone HTML file, but I don't know where the printed text is coming from (it's not found anywhere in the code you provided).

Check your `document.getElementById(problemFormId)` calls...you may be setting the field to a text variable yourself without realizing it.

Comment: I've gotten the entirety of the text being sent to my +Dur field: it's returning this string: function hour(serial_number){if(!isFinite(serial_number))return Number.NaN;var res=Math.floor((serial_number-Math.floor(serial_number))*86400+0.5);return Math.floor(res/3600);} : 00 : 34            the time at the end is all I want.  I've gotten the issue handled about the refreshing of the page (it no longer does that). I'd like to know why it's returning not only the value I asked for but also what appears to be part of the code generating the value.

Comment: also, it's not clearing any of the values when pressing 'reset'.   However, on a good note the time values for start and end fields are posting.